# Force articles to openright with combine class

Tags: double-sided, combine

I'm using the `combine` class to combine several articles into a single document.  I would like each document to start on the right, similar to the `openright` option available on the book class.

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see whic h combination of packages and options you are trying.  Also, usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\cleardoublepage` before each `\import`.